# Matlab Callback Function Only Sees one Parameter Passed to it

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, callback

I'm writing my first GUI programmatically in Matlab. I have built the visual aspect of the GUI and I am now in the process of writing the Callback functions. When I write the callback function I need to pass two handles to it, but for some reason only one of the handles is passed to the function. I'm sure this is really quite a basic question but I am really struggling to get past this, and I can't find any reason in the documentation why this wouldn't work

The callback is for a button and takes two user inputted parameters, and then uses these numbers to build a transfer function. The two parameters are entered into editable text boxes, with handles orderEdit and timeConstEdit. I can extract the string which I need and then convert it to an numeric data format. The code is as follows

First I set the callback flag to the button rtdButton

```
set( rtdButton, 'Callback', @rtdPlot );
```

The first two lines of the callback function are as follows (the rest of the function should work once I can get these values):

```
function rtdPlot(orderEdit,timeConstEdit)
    n = str2num(get( orderEdit, 'String' ));
    tau = str2num(get( timeConstEdit, 'String' ));
```

However I get the Error

```
??? Error using ==> str2num at 33
Requires string or character array input.

Error in ==> mixingModel>rtdPlot at 148
         tau = str2num(get( timeConstEdit, 'String' ));

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated

Edit: Based on Bee's post the correct code is as follows:

set( rtdButton, 'Callback', {@rtdPlot,orderEdit, timeConstEdit} );

```
    function rtdPlot(src,eventdata,arg1,arg2)
        n = str2num(get( orderEdit, 'String' ));
        tau = str2num(get( timeConstEdit, 'String' ));
```

Cheers
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Matlab documentation:

> You can define the callback function to accept additional input
>   arguments by adding them to the function definition:
>
> function myCallback(src,eventdata,arg1,arg2) When using additional
>   arguments for the callback function, you must set the value of the
>   property to a cell array (i.e., enclose the function handle and
>   arguments in curly braces):
>
> figure('WindowButtonDownFcn',{@myCallback,arg1,arg2})

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/function-handle-callbacks.html

Comment: Another useful idiom is `set(handle, 'Callback', @(a, b)function(a, b, c, d));`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Write Code for Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/writing-code-for-callbacks.html#f16-1001315), especially the section **Use Cell Array Callbacks**:

> If you need to specify arguments for a callback, you can wrap a
>   function name string or function handle and the arguments in a cell
>   array.
>
> - Identify the callback as a string to execute a file having that name, for example, `pushbutton_callback.m`.
> - Identify the callback as a    function handle to execute a local function or nested function in the    currently executing code file,
>     for example, `@pushbutton_callback`.

Answer (score 1):

One way as already mentioned is to enclose the function handle and the additional arguments within a cell array:

```
set(rtdButton, 'Callback', {@rtdPlot, orderEdit, timeConstEdit})
function rtdPlot(src, eventdata, orderEdit, timeConstEdit)
```

Alternatively, you can define callbacks as **nested functions**, without passing a cell structure but a simply `@callback`:

```
function mainGui
% Create main gui graphical elements here and collect graphic handles into a structure
h.pushb(1) = ...
h.pushb(2) = ...
...

    function pb1_callback(src,event)
        % h.pushb(1) and others are visible
    end

end
```