# MATLAB GUI Access handles

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am creating a MATLAB GUI that needs to listen to key press information and then update the screen accordingly. This would not be a problem if the callback function for a key press actually had access to the `handles` object, but it does not. Is there a way to give this callback access to the `handles` object?

This is how I start my key listener.

```
set(hObject,'KeyPressFcn',@keyDownListener)
```

Then I try to handle this in a the defined function

```
function keyDownListener(src,event)    
    % need access to handles
end
```

I have to imagine it is simple, but I can not seem to find a good answer for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do the following:

```
set(hObject,'KeyPressFcn',{@keyDownListener,handles})
```

and then define the function as:

```
function keyDownListener(src,event,handles)
```

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that in the documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add addtional parameters to your keyDownListener-fcn. There is a special syntax to do this, as explained here:

[matlab-callback-function-only-sees-one-parameter-passed-to-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693464/matlab-callback-function-only-sees-one-parameter-passed-to-it)